# How to rebuild the modules sequence

Tags: magento2, module, configuration

**TL:DR;**
How can I rebuild (automatically) the modules sequence stored in `app/etc/config.php` in Magento 2.
**Long version:**
I have 2 modules I'm working on.
I installed them in the order "Module 1", "Module 2".
So in my `app/etc/config.php` they appear at the bottom like this:

```
'Magento_Wishlist' => 1, //core module
'Namespace_Module1' => 1, //my first module
'Namespace_Module2' => 1, //my second module
```

But after I installed both of them, I realized that Module2 must be loaded before Module1 so that some config settings from Module 2 can be overwritten through Module 1.  (don't ask why, just bear with me).

So I edited the `etc/module.xml` file of "Module1" and added the "Module 2" inside the `<sequence>` tag.
But that has no effect, because the list of modules from `config.php` remains the same.
Is there a way to rebuild the sequence from `config.php`? I know that for 2 modules it should be easy because I can just edit it manually, but I'm curious if there is an automated way of doing it, in case I will need it in the future.

Comment: Did you try disabling/re enabling both modules ? Setup upgrade ?

Comment: I guess that could work, but I was trying not to disable them. I was hoping for a clean approach. And I don't even think that both need to be disabled. One should be enough. You can put that as an answers, and If nobody comes with a solution that does not involve disabling modules I will take that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

> If you change the component load order using `<sequence>`, you must
>   regenerate the component list in `config.php`; otherwise, the load order
>   does not take effect.
>
> Currently, the only way to do this is to enable the component using
>   `magento module:enable <module-list>`, where `<module-list>` is the
>   component or components to which you added `<sequence>`.

Comment: Ah. Since this is from the documentation it must be the only valid option. I guess I have to go with this.

Comment: I find that if you don't use the right keywords you can miss useful information on the documentation